# Fetch each item from Array list in RxJava

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2

How can i get each user from  `Observable<ArrayList<user>>` to process with some other observable before the subscriber subscribe to it. I searched it on Stack overflow and got it know about `flatMapIterable()` but still its not working.How would i do this in Rxjava2 ? Please tell me anybody..

Comment: What have you so far? What do you mean by "process with some other observable"?

Comment: I have to fetch each user detail from database . I'll do those things in Flatmap method where i'll create second observable to collect each user detail from my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a typical flatMap situation:

```
Observable<ArrayList<User>> users = ...

users.flatMapIterable(list -> list)
     .flatMap(user -> db.getUserDetails(user))
     .subscribe(user -> { /* ... */ }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Comment: flatmapIterable() is not gonna work here as it takes a list of type User.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? What is the compilation error?